# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index even if I'm passing an integer

Tags: python

can you explain to me why

```
New_File = FILE[0:39474, ...]
```

FILE is a np.array and Index is the result of a np.where operation

works fine, while if I instead replace 39474 with a variable containing it

```
Index[0]
```

where Index is 1x1 vector, in fact

`print(Index[0])` shows [39474]

I get `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

I also tried applying cast `Index[0].astype(int)` and putting in the code like

```
New_File = FILE[0:Index[0].astype(int), ...]
```

but I still get the same error!

I'm just replacing the number with the variable containing it, why is it saying index[0] (which contains the same integer) is not a integer?

Comment: What are `FILE` and `Index`? `ndarray`s? Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: print(Index[0]) shows [39474] looks like index[0] is.a list :),not an integer, try Index[0][0] for debugging

Comment: @ggorlen FILE is a np.array and Index is the result of a np.where operation

Comment: @E.Serra that works, thank you. But since I'm using np.array maybe best thing would be converting the list into a np.array too. I'll look into it. Thx for the debugging advice

Comment: Please show them as simple examples. You can make up a small piece of code that reproduces the problem when executed. This eliminates ambiguity that prevents people from assisting you and prevents the post from being helpful to future visitors. Effectively, you're asking us to guess what your data is using circumstantial evidence, which may be possible but is also likely not to be.